# Multiple Textareas using the SummerNote JS Editor saving issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, summernote

I have a form with for example 10 TEXTAREAS which need to be editable and when save will save any changes of those TEXTAREAS, however, I have integrated the JS Editor Summernote (https://summernote.org/examples/)

I have a PHP loop that generates the TEXTAREAS and with the following JS is it showing the editor for each TEXTAREA however when i make changes to either of the content areas of the editors and save it does not save the content.... does anyone have any ideas?

**JS**

```
$(function () {
  //ENABLES TEXT EDITOR
  $('textarea.editor').summernote();
})
```

**HTML Example:**

```
<textarea id='en_info_received_content' class='editor form-control textarea' rows='4' name='en_info_received_content'>test content info</textarea>
<textarea id='en_delivered_content' class='editor form-control textarea' rows='4' name='en_delivered_content'>test content info</textarea>
<textarea id='en_failed_content' class='editor form-control textarea' rows='4' name='en_failed_content'>test content info</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to place each `<textarea>` within it's own `<form>` so when an individual textarea's form is submitted and data sent to your backend script it has the relevant information to store the data.

Comment: Yea that would be a method for sure, but all the text areas are within 1 form.... surely if I can generate the editor on all the textareas I can save them... I actually did some JS functions that would check for change on the editor, find the parent (hidden) textarea and update the value and done the trick but does not always update all of them as rather a lot so works and some... sometimes don't haha

Comment: I'm not sure if the Summernote API is interfering with your script for saving the data, I don't think it would be (could be wrong though).

My only suggestions would be to have the `textarea`'s in separate forms so they don't interfere as I previously suggested.

Or process all the areas with one form submit. I guess the only thing you would need to watch is the amount of data being sent.